# Get selected items value for Bootstrap's typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Bootstrap just implemented a neat autocomplete feature called typeahead. I am having trouble getting the appropriate value for the text input.

For instance, I might have the following:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This does not appear to capture the selected value. Does anyone know how to get the selected value using typeahead with Bootstrap?

Comment: At the risk of shameless self promotion, I added functionality to that plugin because I found it too primitive for real-world scenarios (using complex JSON sources, performing an action when an item is selected.)  You can see it [here](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) and at the very least you may understand how to manipulate the results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11747290/212702

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$('#autocomplete').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
});
$('#autocomplete').on('typeahead:cursorchanged', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
});
```

Seems Typeahead changed listeners and usages are not well documented. You can use these listeners.

**UPDATE**

Event name was changed to `typeahead:select` in later versions.

Comment: this is the official solution

Comment: wonder why this answer is not marked correct .. though this is the perfect answer

Comment: @Rohit (and others commenting on why this isn't the selected answer) - Because the original question is about [Bootstrap2 typeahead](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead), and this answer is for the newer, standalone [Twitter Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md), which was not yet available in 2012.

Comment: Please note that the event name was changed to typeahead:select in later versions.

Comment: @ymutlu I get `undefined` when I try to pass in `datum.id`. What can I do to access user id to make it a clickable link to the users show page?

Answer (score 23):

You're looking at it from the wrong angle.  Bootstrap's typeahead method provides an option which allows you to pass a callback function that receives the selected value as the argument.  Below is a condensed example illustrating just this one argument.

```
$('#typeaheadID').typeahead({
    updater: function(selection){
        console.log("You selected: " + selection)
    }
})
```

cheers!
[documentation refernece](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)

Comment: The important thing is to return the selection from the updater function. Otherwise the input field will be empty

Comment: This only works if the user has actually selected an item. If I want the value currently highlighted, rather than selected, this will not work.

Comment: This works, it should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'm working with this and I'm having the same issue right now. I'm planning to solve it with this pretty fork

https://gist.github.com/1891669

And I did it with a callback:

```
  $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    // note that "value" is the default setting for the property option
    source: [{value: 'Charlie'}, {value: 'Gudbergur'}, ...],
    onselect: function(obj) { console.log(obj) }
  })
```

Hope it helps you too.

Comment: I eventually figured out how to do this. You can do it in jQuery using this: $("ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu").find('li.active').data('value');

Answer (score 4):

If you only had 1 on the page you could try `$('ul.typeahead li.active').data('value');` but you may have have issues if there's more than 1 on a page.

I wonder if there's a reason why the input value is not set?

Comment: This worked for me inside blur event on the select box:

$(this).parent().find("ul.typeahead li.active").data("value")

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myselector').typeahead({
itemSelected:function(data,value,text){
   console.log(data)
    alert('value is'+value);
    alert('text is'+text);
},
//your other stuffs
});
```

You have to just pass itemSelected in the callback function and it will give you the selected item.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using another button to work with selected item or need get this item not right after update you can use `$("#your_input").next("ul").find("li.active").data("value");` to get your value.

Working for ajax bootstrap typeahead.