# bootstrap-typeahead.js add a listener on select event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to the Bootstrap Twitter framework, and I need to use bootstrap-typeahead.js for autocomplete but I need also to get the value selected by the user for the typeahead.

This is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" 
                   data-provide="typeahead" data- items="4" 
                   data-source='["Alabama","Alaska"]'>
```

How can I add a listener to get the selected value from type typeahead and pass it in a function? For example when I use ExtJs, I apply this structure:

```
listeners: {
   select: function(value){
     ........
   }
}
```

How can I do something similar with a typeahead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [this fork of typeahead](https://gist.github.com/1891669). It gives you an onselect event, asynchronous population and more!

Comment: typeahead now has `afterSelect`, see my answer

Answer (score 168):

you should use "**updater**":

```js
$('#search-box').typeahead({

    source: ["foo", "bar"],

    updater:function (item) {

        //item = selected item
        //do your stuff.

        //dont forget to return the item to reflect them into input
        return item;
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked with 2.1. However the documentation has not yet been updated `updater` option. I am submitting a pull-request now

Comment: Actually I made my own method 'delegate' that is being called inside select method, until I found this question, I waste time for that. Thanks for this.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the selected item's index in the updater function? I'm asking here since there is still no documentation in the docs

Comment: But if the textbox is prefilled, and the user press enter (therefore no autocomplete will happen as the text in the textbox is already), updater wouldn't get fired it seems.

Comment: this does not work. for example when you want after select focus on some other control.

Comment: I have spent hours chasing around with permutations of 'typeahead:selected' event with no results. But this actually worked, THANK YOU...

Comment: this doesn't work any longer. Maybe only worked in old version of typeahead?

Answer (score 55):

In v3 twitter bootstrap typeahead will be dropped an replaced with the twitter typeahead (which has the feature you want to and a lot more)

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

usage like this:

```
jQuery('#autocomplete-input').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
});
```

Comment: but how do I use typeahead:selected?

Comment: I'd suggest using `.on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted'...` to also capture autocompletion when a user presses the tab key, as mentioned in @philippinedev's answer below.

Answer (score 19):

you can use  `afterSelect`

```
$('#someinput').typeahead({ 
    source: ['test1', 'test2'], 
    afterSelect: function (item) {
        // do what is needed with item
        //and then, for example ,focus on some other control
        $("#someelementID").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work in the latest version of typeahead

Answer (score 17):

Thanks P.scheit for your answer.  Let me just add this to your solution which handles autocompletion when user presses the tab key.

```
jQuery('#autocomplete-input').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
}).on('typeahead:autocompleted', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
});
```

Comment: I dont think we need seperate on functions i have given a modified version below, thanks for the initial input..

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to get this working by simply watching the "change" event on the element, which Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead fires on select.

```
var onChange = function(event) {
  console.log "Changed: " + event.target.value
};

$('input.typeahead').typeahead({ source: ['test1', 'test2'] });
$('input.typeahead').on('change', onChange);
```

Outputs 'Changed: test1' when the user selects test1.

NOTE: It also fires the event when the user presses "Enter" even if no match is found, so you have to decide if that's what you want.  Especially, if the user enters "te" and then clicks "test1", you will get an event for "te" and an event for "test1", which you may want to debounce.

(Version 2.0.2 Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead)

Answer (score 2):

Heres the solution with multi-event on for tabbed and selected:

```
$('#remote .typeahead').on(
    {
        'typeahead:selected': function(e, datum) {
            console.log(datum);
            console.log('selected');
        },
        'typeahead:autocompleted': function(e, datum) {
            console.log(datum);
            console.log('tabbed');
        }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. When I do it your suggested way, second option does not fire. Double 'on' seems safer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. You can use this function to make your custom events: https://github.com/finom/Functions/tree/master/FunctionCallEvent#why-is-it-needed
(to add more events you have to know typeahead prototype structure)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({ 
    source: ['test1', 'test2'], 
    itemSelected: function(e){ 
        ---your code here---
    } 
});
```

Comment: //  Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead Plugin
//  v1.2.2
//  https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead

Comment: ...  explain it ...in your answer.