# Handle selected event in autocomplete textbox using bootstrap Typeahead?

Tags: autocomplete, textbox, typeahead

I want to run JavaScript function just after **user select a value** using **autocomplete textbox bootstrap Typeahead**.

I'm searching for something like **selected** event.

Comment: link to  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11747290/212702

Comment: True answer is not the one selected though...:(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$('.typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function(evt, item) {
    // do what you want with the item here
})
```

Comment: This approach works for https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ not for the twitter bootstrap. (typeahead is now separated from twitter bootstrap)

Comment: is there any way to get the key pressed for this handler? the evt var doesn't seem to have a 'which' propery

Answer (score 19):

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    updater: function(item) {
        // do what you want with the item here
        return item;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

For an explanation of the way typeahead works for what you want to do here, taking the following code example:

HTML input field:

```
<input type="text" id="my-input-field" value="" />
```

JavaScript code block:

```
$('#my-input-field').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get('json-page.json', { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data.options);
        });
    },
    updater: function(item) {
        myOwnFunction(item);
        var $fld = $('#my-input-field');
        return item;
    }
})
```

Explanation:

1. Your input field is set as a typeahead field with the first line: `$('#my-input-field').typeahead(`
2. When text is entered, it fires the `source:` option to fetch the JSON list and display it to the user.
3. If a user clicks an item (or selects it with the cursor keys and enter), it then runs the `updater:` option. *Note that it hasn't yet updated the text field with the selected value*.
4. You can grab the selected item using the `item` variable and do what you want with it, e.g. `myOwnFunction(item)`.
5. I've included an example of creating a reference to the input field itself `$fld`, in case you want to do something with it. *Note that you can't reference the field using $(this)*.
6. You **must** then include the line `return item;` within the `updater:` option so the input field is actually updated with the `item` variable.

Answer (score 5):

first time i've posted an answer on here (plenty of times I've found an answer here though), so here's my contribution, hope it helps. You should be able to detect a change - try this:

```
function bob(result) {
    alert('hi bob, you typed: '+ result);
}

$('#myTypeAhead').change(function(){
    var result = $(this).val()
    //call your function here
    bob(result);
});
```

Comment: Have marked down because this is not the supported nor recommended way to handle selected elements on typeahead, see here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js at: typahead:selected

Answer (score 4):

According to their [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#api), the proper way of handling `selected` event is by using this event handler:

```
$('#selector').on('typeahead:select', function(evt, item) {
    console.log(evt)
    console.log(item)
    // Your Code Here
})
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is below:

```
$('#someinput').typeahead({ 
    source: ['test1', 'test2'], 
    afterSelect: function (item) {
        // do what is needed with item
        //and then, for example ,focus on some other control
        $("#someelementID").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: The link no longer works.

Comment: No worries, the solution was already copied from there. I'm going to remove the link.

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension that includes that feature.

https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead

Comment: Link is broken right now. Is this the repository? https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead

Comment: Sorry I updated the link a while ago, as of Apr 29th it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get(
        url, 
        { query: query }, 
        function (data) {
            limit: 10,
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            return process(data);
        }
    );
},
afterSelect: function(item) {
    $("#divId").val(item.id);
    $("#divId").val(item.name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully working example with some tricks. Assuming you are searching for trademarks and you want to get the selected trademark Id.

In your view MVC,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TrademarkName, new { id = "txtTrademarkName", @class = "form-control",
   autocomplete = "off", dataprovide = "typeahead" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TrademarkId, new { id = "hdnTrademarkId" })
```

Html

```
<input type="text" id="txtTrademarkName" autocomplete="off" dataprovide="typeahead" class="form-control" value="" maxlength="100" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnTrademarkId" />
```

In your JQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var trademarksHashMap = {};
var lastTrademarkNameChosen = "";

$("#txtTrademarkName").typeahead({
    source: function (queryValue, process) {
        // Although you receive queryValue, 
        // but the value is not accurate in case of cutting (Ctrl + X) the text from the text box.
        // So, get the value from the input itself.
        queryValue = $("#txtTrademarkName").val();
        queryValue = queryValue.trim();// Trim to ignore spaces.

        // If no text is entered, set the hidden value of TrademarkId to null and return.
        if (queryValue.length === 0) {
            $("#hdnTrademarkId").val(null);
            return 0;
        }

        // If the entered text is the last chosen text, no need to search again.
        if (lastTrademarkNameChosen === queryValue) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Set the trademarkId to null as the entered text, doesn't match anything.
        $("#hdnTrademarkId").val(null);

        var url = "/areaname/controllername/SearchTrademarks";
        var params = { trademarkName: queryValue };

        // Your get method should return a limited set (for example: 10 records) that starts with {{queryValue}}.
        // Return a list (of length 10) of object {id, text}.
        return $.get(url, params, function (data) {
            // Keeps the current displayed items in popup.
            var trademarks = [];

            // Loop through and push to the array.
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var itemToDisplay = item.text;
                trademarksHashMap[itemToDisplay] = item;
                trademarks.push(itemToDisplay);
            });

            // Process the details and the popup will be shown with the limited set of data returned.
            process(trademarks);
        });
    },
    updater: function (itemToDisplay) {

        // The user selectes a value using the mouse, now get the trademark id by the selected text. 
        var selectedTrademarkId = parseInt(trademarksHashMap[itemToDisplay].value);
        $("#hdnTrademarkId").val(selectedTrademarkId);

        // Save the last chosen text to prevent searching if the text not changed.
        lastTrademarkNameChosen = itemToDisplay;

        // return the text to be displayed inside the textbox.
        return itemToDisplay;
    }
  });

});
```