# How to fill the second field on the basis of the input from first field LIVE

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, typeahead.js, auto-populate

I have two input fields 1. Name , 2. Telephone. All i want is (1. When I start typing name it must search from database for autocomplete Now when the Name is selected from search query i want Telephone input to be filled automatically on the basis on Name selected.
Currently I'm using typeahead.js to autocomplete the Name search.

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahed.js"></script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #111;
        }

        .content {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        .tt-hint,
        .Name {
            border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 45px;
            line-height: 30px;
            outline: medium none;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            width: 400px;
        }

        .tt-dropdown-menu {
            width: 400px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #111;
            background-color: #F1F1F1;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.Name').typeahead({
                name: 'Name',
                remote: 'city.php?query=%QUERY'

            });

        })
    </script>




</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">

        <form>
            <h1>Try it yourself</h1>
            <input type="text" name="Name" size="30" class="Name" placeholder="Please Enter Name or ZIP code"> </input>

            <input type="text" name="Telephone" size="30" class="Telephone" placeholder="Telephone"> </input>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My PHP Code :
//Not putting database connection part (Obviously i have connected it)

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $sql = mysqli_query ($conn,"SELECT Name,Telephone FROM customerdetails WHERE Name LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $shu[] = array (
            'label' => $row['Name'],
            'value' => $row['Name'],

        );
    }

    echo json_encode ($shu);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The script `city.php` have to return values for names and telephone number. 
   In your example you have twice `$row['Name']`.
2. You have to separate the values that the names are used for the original typeahead search (try *template* like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41283717/7617251)) and the telephone number is used when a name is selected.
   Not used to typeahead but found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16834198/7617251) which looks solid to me to achive what you want.

   ```
   $('input.Name').typeahead({
       name: 'Name',
       remote: 'city.php?query=%QUERY',
       updater: function(item) {
           // try to get telephone number out of "item" and set it to the telephone number field
           return item;
       }
   });
   ```

What version of typeahead are you using? https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js? Maybe you need to include the [bloodhound suggestion module](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md)...