# Run function right after the input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bootstrap-typeahead.js add a listener on select event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496314/bootstrap-typeahead-js-add-a-listener-on-select-event)

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's typeahead functionality, and I want to use `.on('change', function(){...})`, but my problem is, the event fires before the value of the input actually changes to the one selected, and when the function is called, the `$(this).val()` inside the function returns the value that was there before the change. The event fires twice, but only the second one should.

I need a way to run the function in a way so it returns the selected value, and runs only once.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/ZUhFy/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the updater property:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUhFy/10/

```
.typeahead({
        source: namelist,
        updater: function(item) {
            $('#log').append(item + '<br>');
            return item;
        }
    });
```

> updater   returns selected item   The method used to return selected item.
>   Accepts a single argument, the item and has the scope of the typeahead
>   instance. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: Awesome! I guess I didn't understand that part of the documentation properly...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#findname').on('keyup', function() {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try using the `keyup`

```
.on('keyup', function(){...})
```

Comment: Keyup will not work, since I only want to run the function when the users decide what they select. That would fire every time they type something.