# jQuery throws a typeError using typeahead updater parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

If you visit my website with Google Chrome at [http://djdavid98.zymichost.com/.tagguide/](http://djdavid98.zymichost.com/.tagguide/?lang=en&seen=felfogtam&betatest=true), and try to use the search box (eg. type 'a', click first option), you will see that in the console, jQuery logs an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. I don't see why.

The problem must be in this part of the code, because removing it fixes everything:

**[tagguide.js](http://djdavid98.zymichost.com/js/tagguide.js) (line 20-46):**

```
$('#findname').typeahead({
    ...
    updater : function (item) {
        $('#ponies li:contains('+$(this).val()+')').parent().parent().parent().addClass('in');
        ...
    },
});

$('#findpony').typeahead({
    ...
    updater : function(item){
        $('#'+$('div.accordion-group > div > a.accordion-toggle:contains('+$(this).val()+')').attr('id')).addClass('in');
        ...
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually on the line in the minified jQuery file with the arrows pointing to it:

**`2148`**

```
val: function( value ) {
    var hooks, ret, isFunction,
        elem = this[0];

    if ( !arguments.length ) {
        if ( elem ) {
            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] ||
                    jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ]; //<<<<<<<

                if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && 
                     (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
                return ret;
        }

        ret = elem.value;

        return typeof ret === "string" ?
            // handle most common string cases
            ret.replace(rreturn, "") :
            // handle cases where value is null/undef or number
            ret == null ? "" : ret;
    }

    return;
}​
```

**`2174`**

I've noticed that Chrome console will at times "lose" it's place when locating the errors; they're all soon be found in the same spot. You just have to manually refresh the path to get it reset.

The solution turned out to be two-fold to substitute `item` from the callback argument for `$(this).val()`, which was throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error in jquery is thrown from calling `.val()` of undefined

its this line

```
$('#ponies li:contains('+$(this).val()+')').parent().parent().parent().addClass('in');
```

try

```
$('#ponies li:contains(a)').parent().parent().parent().addClass('in');
```

that would simulate what the value would be if you only typed in "a" in the text box , if that works then you need to get .val() of `$('#findname')` instead of `$(this)`

reading farther into that code I believe the reason the `$(this)` is returning `undefined` is beacause it is being called after 2 `.attr()` in this code:

```
$('#findpony').attr('placeholder',function(){
    // code removed     
}).attr('title',function(){
            // code removed
}).typeahead({
    source  : ponylist,
    updater : function(item){ 
        $('#'+$('div.accordion-group > div > a.accordion-toggle:contains('+$(this).val()+')').attr('id')).addClass('in');
        return item;
    },
});
```

see - you are calling #(this) after  $('#findpony').attr('placeholder').attr('title')

Comment: Changed the order, still nothing.

Comment: try using $('#findname') instead of $(this)

Comment: Why is `item` not being used? It's what's being sent in from the callback.And there's no way those selectors an chained `parent()` functions make any sense.

Comment: It's returned at the end for the plugin to use. I got this code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104127/run-function-right-after-the-input-changes)

Comment: @ScottSelby Now it's sent, but with a bad value.

Comment: @DJDavid98 - Have you modified that script? Or is it old? It doesn't look anything like the one in their dcos: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js

Comment: The typehead script is included in my `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: @DJDavid98 - So it's working now? Good. I was wondering why `item` was getting ignored but `this` was being used in a callback.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Mind posting an answer that says replace `$(this).val()` with `item`, so I can accept something?