# Twitter-Typeahead isn't offering suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use `twitter-typeahead-rails`. My intention is for instances of the model "User" to be suggested via a drop-down box as I type into the "#Typeahead" input box. However, nothing happens when I type.

Does anyone see anything that could be wrong with my code?

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
```

**layouts/application.js:**

```
//= require twitter/typeahead
//= require twitter/typeahead/bloodhound
```

**config/routes.rb:**

```
get 'typeahead/:query' => 'users#typeahead'
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb:**

```
def typeahead
  render json: User.where(name: params[:query])
end
```

**views/users/show.html.erb:**

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY', 
    limit: 50
  });
  bloodhound.initialize();

  $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
  });

  $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
    doSomething(datum.id);
  });
</script>
```

I'm not getting any errors in the web console, and all the necessary files are apparently being included:

**Page source**

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/typeahead.bundle.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/typeahead.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/typeahead/bloodhound.js?body=1"></script>
```

**Network console:**

[image: Headers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

Try wrapping the javascript code with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  /* the bloodhound, typeahead and bind script */ 
})
```

There are probability that the element it was binding has not yet been initialized when the javascript code executed.

**EDIT 2**

Try changing from:

```
render json: User.where(name: params[:query])
```

Into:

```
q = params[:query]
render json: User.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{q}%")

# alternate syntax:
#render json: User.where('name LIKE :x', x: "%#{q}%")

# or when you want case-insensitive search:
#q = params[:query].to_s.downcase
#render json: User.where('LOWER(name) LIKE ?, "%#{q}%")
```

So the suggestion would give all with substring result, instead of exact match.

**OLD ANSWER**

This is not the correct answer, but it's worth to try. This works on debugging any web-app/ajax-app.

To debug, first, you'll need to use `google-chrome`, `firefox` or `opera`, `right click` on the window and do `inspect element`, now try to type on the typeahead input field. If there any red icon with number appearing? such as:

[image: error number]

If there so, just visit the `console` tab:

[image: console tab]

and see, what part of the javascript that causing the error, fix it (or you could tell me in the comment).

Few possible errors are:

- javascript syntax error
- wrong ajax target

If there are no error, click on the network tab:

[image: network tab]

look up the ajax sent when typing the typeahead input field, first check the `headers` sub tab, make user that the `Form Data` are correct (you're sending the right message to the server).

[image: headers sub tab form data]

Secondly check the `response` sub tab, is it correct or not? If it's incorrect (the server give wrong output/format), then the server side is at fault, check the source of controller/action that generates the response (see the rails log or `headers` sub tab). If its already correct, most likely the bug of the library.

[image: response sub tab]

We could not help you any more without specific error message, because I believe it'll took quite a time just to reproduce your code (installing ruby+rails+gems, setting up one table, create the model, and pasting stuff that you've wrote in the question).

Comment: There are no errors in 'inspect element' or in the js web console. I went to the 'Network' tab, however, I can't find the 'headers' or 'response' subtabs...where exactly are they? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: On the network tab, there should be a new row named `/typeahead/what-you've-typed` that shown when typeahead field sent an ajax request, click on that row in  `Name/Path` column, there would be a new sub-window containing sub-tabs: `Headers`, `Preview`, `Response`, `Cookies` and `Timing`.

Comment: My "Name" column is completely empty. I don't think any ajax requests are being sent.

Comment: try typing a longer word on typeahead input field.

Comment: secondly, try to wrap your script with `$(document).ready(function(){
 /* the bloodhound, typeahead and bind script */
})`, there are possibility that the typeahead field not yet rendered when the javascript code executed.

Comment: Nice, wrapping it worked! Okay, under the Response tab it just says "[]". Under Headers however, I don't see any Form Data; all I see are "Remote Address", "Request URL", "Request Method", "Status Code", "Request Headers", and "Response Headers".

Comment: It would only shown when any row/requests (`Name`/`Path` column) clicked

Comment: I posted a screenshot of my Network tab above, with the full contents of the Headers subtab (everything is visible; scrolling down doesn't reveal any more elements). Where can I find Form Data?

Comment: ah i see, because the ajax request is a `GET` method not a `POST` method, so `form data` won't be visible in the `Headers` tab..

Comment: Oh I see. No, nothing changed.

Comment: Could you send me the `Response` sub-tab content? when typing anything that exists in the database

Comment: Try changing the `User.where(name: params[:query])` with this:
`q = params[:query]; render json: User.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{q}%")`

Comment: haha :) By the way, do think I could make the suggestions that drop down link somewhere? Like if I wanted each user to `link_to` the `user_path`, do you think that's possible?

Comment: I don't really understand your last question? something like this? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns or dropdown that given by typeahead component?

Comment: When I start to type, a list drops down with suggestions. If I type "Jo", the list will contain items like "Joe", "Joseph", "John", etc. If I click on "Joe", the form is filled in with "Joe". But instead, I would like to be immediately redirected to Joe's profile. Is that clear enough?

Comment: I see, just use this answer, that has 140+ vote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496314/bootstrap-typeahead-js-add-a-listener-on-select-event