# How to perform Bootstrap Typeaheads with on click linking to the results another page

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Here is my code...and using codeigniter framework. am trying to redirect the results to another page like if car is bmw , on click on the result, it will redirect to like welcome/bmw . Is it posible to do ? Please help me with the codes...

```
$(document).ready(function(){   var cars = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen'];   var cars = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: cars });// Initializing the typeahead
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true, /* Enable substring highlighting */
    minLength: 1 /* Specify minimum characters required for showing suggestions */
},
{
    name: 'cars',
    source: cars
}); });
```

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496314/bootstrap-typeahead-js-add-a-listener-on-select-event#answer-11747290

Comment: Not working..i need to edirect the results to another page