# How to alter Bootstrap's typeahead selected value?

Tags: replace, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I retrieve the selected typeahead value by using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459437/get-selected-items-value-for-bootstraps-typeahead):

`$('ul.typeahead li.active').data('value');`

I then set this equal to a variable, like so,

`var foo = $('ul.typeahead li.active').data('value');`

However, if I try and do something like this:

`var foo = $('ul.typeahead li.active').data('value').replace( /\([^\)]+\)$/, '' );`

it won't seem to update the value of foo even though when I console.log(foo) it actually is showing the right value for foo.

Can you please tell me what I could do to resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean that it "won't seem to update the value of foo even though when I console.log(foo) it actually is showing the right value for foo"? If it is showing the right value, then isn't the value, by definition, updated? Or did you mean that the `data-value` attribute isn't being updated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11747290/212702

Answer (score 1):

Data returns an object and not a String

Try :

```
var foo = $('ul.typeahead li.active').data('value').first.replace( /\([^\)]+\)$/, '' );
```