# How to set a textbox value with the selected value of Bootstrap Typeahead?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap

I have the following gwt-bootstrap ui.xml :

```
<b:Typeahead ui:field="typeahead">
   <b:TextBox ui:field="searchBox" searchQuery="true"
     placeholder="Search..." />
</b:Typeahead>
```

How can i programmatically take the suggested response "On Click" of the the typeahead item and set it as Text into the searchbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the Adarsha Answer dont really work in my case, because i use full gwt. So my Solution is :

```
typeahead.setUpdaterCallback(new Typeahead.UpdaterCallback() {

        @Override
        public String onSelection(Suggestion selectedSuggestion) {
            String text = selectedSuggestion.getDisplayString();
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The below link will definitely helps you -

[Get selected items value for Bootstrap's typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459437/get-selected-items-value-for-bootstraps-typeahead)

once you get the selected value its just a matter of doing textbox.setValue(value).