# How to get current selected value in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, echo

I am new to `PHP` development. I wan to echo the selected value in a container and show it as and 'echo'. In the code `<div id="selected_mters_container"></div>` have the serial number. A jquery call is made and the selected meter serial number is displayed like shown below

[image]

Now i want to save this serial number in a variable. Below is the `JQuery`

```
  jQuery('#the-mter-id').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
        $('#selected_mters_container').html('');
        $('#metersinventorystore-store_id').val('');            
        $('#metersinventorystore-historic').val('');
        var html = '<div class="selcted-meters"><input type="hidden" name="selected_meters[]" value="'+datum.id+'" />'+datum.meter_serial+'<a onclick="$(this).closest(\'.selcted-meters\').remove()">X</a></div>';
        $('#selected_mters_container').append(html);
        $('#metersinventorystore-store_id').val(datum.store_id);
        $('#the-mter-id').typeahead('val','');
        $('#metersinventorystore-historic').val(datum.historic);



     });
```

As a newbie I don't know how to do it

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: what did you try?
Can you show us the full html of that form?

Comment: are you trying to use jQuery to grab the entered value and display to the user or are you trying to get a value from a php script and display it to the user?

Comment: possible duplicate if I understand your question correctly https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459663/1231402

Comment: I want to get the value so the answer help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
var theVALUE = $('#selected_mters_container').html();
alert(theVALUE);
```

Comment: Ok, Sorry about the question asked, actually I was misunderstood the code. actually your code works but it gives me the html instead of the value so, here is the correct one `var theVALUE = datum.meter_serial;
                          alert(theVALUE);`